# What is the highest online ranking achievable?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

I know that as you make your way through ranked matches that you slowly rise from E5 to higher ranks, but what is the highest rank you can get to? Is it **A1**, or can I raise my rank even higher than that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe A1 is the highest rank you can get, but this isn't accomplished by just playing a lot.

The breakdown is something like this:
- Losing a match as an E rank gives you +40 points or so
- Losing a match as a D rank gives you -10 points

I haven't gotten to C rank, but presumably each rank gets harder and harder to maintain. If you play all the time and always lose, I suspect you will get stuck between E1 and D5 rank as losing in E will move you up, but losing in D will move you down.

If you lose with an A rank it probably subtracts a good deal of rank progress, likely kicking you back down to B.

If anyone can confirm this, that would be awesome. In the meantime I guess I'll just keep playing until I get to C :D

Comment: I'm fairly certain the amount of points you win or lose is dependent on the level of your opponent.

Comment: It's probably modified by that in some way, but the base points are  certainly based on your own rank. As soon as I got to D rank I started getting -10pts for losing a match.